# What phrase or word can I use to describe a bad mix of action?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

This is in a Saudi YouTube series that I'm subtitling; I came across a colloquial word which means literally 'a mixture of melon juice, mango juice and corn', and figuratively expresses a bad course of action, a messy action or bad and uncontrolled management.

For example:

> Tim was a bad boss, his administration was the worst of its kind he gave false promises and spoke about imaginary projects thats why we going to call them شمنجاحبش which is the name of the mix juices

Comment: A 'mare's nest' is semantically appropriate; there are many other expressions you could find by using this as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Consider some of the following.
• *[farrago](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/farrago#Noun)*, “A collection containing a confused variety of miscellaneous things” (typically pejorative)
• *[muddle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/muddle#Noun)*, “A mixture; a confusion; a garble”
• *[melange](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/melange#Noun)*, “A collection containing a variety of miscellaneous things ” (often not pejorative, and has additional sense “A Viennese coffee speciality, half steamed milk and half coffee”)
• *[mingle-mangle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mingle-mangle#Noun)*, “A collection containing a variety of miscellaneous things” (which seems not pejorative; but as a verb it has the sense “To mix in a disorderly way; to make a mess of” which may apply)
• *[mare's nest](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mare%27s_nest#Noun)*, “A confused or complicated situation; a muddle” (but this also has a less-related sense, “A great discovery which turns out to be illusory; a hoax”)

Answer (score 0):

*Fruit punch* is the generic term, but has no particular negative implication.

*Suicide punch* or *suicide soda* is popular (or was so ten years ago) among adolescents. From the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=suicide%20punch%20cup&r=f)

> When you go to a restaurant or fast food place where there is a Soda Fountain, and you take the large cup and go to each of the drinks/sodas, and one by one fill your cup with each one, mixing them all together.

*Suicide punch*, however, is also the name of an alcoholic cocktail, so this may not be appropriate to a Saudi audience.

Answer (score 0):

***Dog's Dinner*** or ***Dog's Breakfast*** seems most appropriate, e.g. "it was a real dog's dinner".

You can also use ***Kettle of fish***, but that is perhaps more obscure.